# Dump all DNS entries from Active Directory DNS using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, dns, active-directory

I need to analyze a large collection of entries stored in an Active Directory DNS server.  Is there a PowerShell method for retrieving all of the entries contained in a zone?

I can find scripts that do DNS lookups based on either hostname or IP; and others to create entries in DNS.  However, I'm looking for a method to dump all DNS entries into a CSV for analysis in another application.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to have DNS management tools installed on the machine (RSAT perhaps), on a new enough version of Windows/PowerShell (probably 2012/v3 or higher). The module is `DnsServer`.

```
Import-Module DnsServer
Get-DnsServerZone -ComputerName MyDC
```

See the other commands:

```
Get-Command -Module DnsServer
```

Or at the [TechNet site](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649850(v=wps.630).aspx).

`Get-DnsServerResourceRecord` is probably the one you want.

[In some circumstances `Get-DnsServerResourceRecord` can return duplicates](https://www.briantist.com/errors/get-dnsserverresourcerecord-returns-duplicate-records-when-sub-domain-matching-zone-exists/) so watch out for that.

Comment: Get-DnsServerResourceRecord is exactly what was looking.  I found the proper document [on this link at TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649863(v=wps.630).aspx).  It led me to the following to get what I needed:  `Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -ComputerName my_dns_server -ZoneName my_zone.com -RRType A`.  Thanks!